# Java rock paper scissor printing the statements oddly

Tags: java, debugging, logic

So here i am trying to create a program that takes an input as an int and then plays a game of Rock paper scissors. It seems to want to reprint statements that it shouldn't be and is skipping printing statements as well. I would love some assistance if possible. I have tried setting up print statements everywhere but it has just been more confusing.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
        public class RPSS{
        //Main method
          public static void main(String[ ] argc) 
          {
            System.out.println("Lets play rock paper scissors");

            Scanner tnt = new Scanner(System.in); 
            String computerHand; // string variable for computer choice
            String userHand; // string variable for user choice
        //    
            String answer = "";
            while (!a

nswer.equals("No") && (!answer.equals("no"))){

          userHand = userHand();
          computerHand = computerHand();
          System.out.println("The User picks " + userHand + " " );
          System.out.print("The Computer picks " + computerHand );

          String winner = getWinner(computerHand, userHand);
          System.out.println(winner);
          System.out.println("play again?");
          answer = tnt.next();
        }

        //Condition for the do-while loop


      }

      public static String userHand(){ //method for users choice in the game

        //prints message to user giving them choices
        System.out.println("     ");
        System.out.println("1. Rock ");
        System.out.println("2. Paper ");
        System.out.println("3. Scissors ");
        int userChoice; // user choice variable in this method
        Scanner tnt = new Scanner(System.in); // creates instance of scanner class
        userChoice = tnt.nextInt(); //reads user input
        return getChoice(userChoice); //returns user choice to userChoice
      }

      public static String computerHand() //method for computer  generated choice 
      {

        int computernum =  1 + (int)(Math.random() * (( 2) +1));
        return getChoice(computernum);
      } 

      public static  String getChoice(int num) //method recieving both computer hand and user hand
      {
        //  if statements to place the correct choice
        String choice = "";
        if (num == 1){
          choice = "Rock";
        }
        else if(num == 2){
          choice = "Paper";
        }
        else if(num == 3){
          choice = "Scissors";
        }
        return choice;
      }
      // Method determing the winner 
      public static String getWinner(String computerChoice, String userChoice) 
      {
        computerChoice = computerHand(); //places computerChoice variable in computerhand
        userChoice = userHand(); //does same for user choice
        String winner="";


        if (userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")){
          System.out.println("The computer wins"); 
           return winner;
        } 

        else if  (userChoice.equals("Paper") && computerChoice.equals("Scissors")){
          System.out.println(" The computer wins"); 
           return winner;
        } 

        else if  (userChoice.equals("Scissors") && computerChoice.equals("Rock")){
          System.out.println(" The computer wins "); 
           return winner;
        } 
        else if (userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")){
          System.out.println(" The computer wins "); 
          return winner;
        } 

        else if(userChoice.equals(computerChoice))
        {
          System.out.println(" There is no winner"); 
          return " ";  
        }
        else{

          return winner;
      } 
      }
    }
```

Comment: it's better to step through your code with a debugger than using print statements to help your way out of a problem

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not a real question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Comment: You seem to be checking `userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")` twice.

Comment: You're not assigning any value (other than the initial "") to the variable `winner` in method `getWinner(String,String)`

Comment: You are also invoking `userHand()` and `computerHand()` twice each game, once in the while loop in the main method, and once again at the start of the `getWinner()` method.

Answer (score 0):

- The first problem is that userhand() and computerHand() are being called twice per "round", once at the beginning of the while loop inside the main method and once at the beginning of the getWinner() method. Elimination of the calls at the beginning of the getWinner() method should solve the repeats.
- The 2nd Problem is that instead of modifying the value of winner inside the getWinner() method before returning it, you are you are simply outputting the message via println(). an example of fixing this would be converting this:

  if (userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper"){
      System.out.println("The computer wins");
      return winner;
  }

  to this:

  if (userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")){
      winner = "The computer wins";
      return winner;
  }
- another minor issue is the fact that

  userChoice.equals("Rock") && computerChoice.equals("Paper")

  is checked twice, id just remove the entire if else block based around the
  2nd check of it
- Lastly i would treat the final else clause as the player wins one and set winner to something like " The player wins "